# Records Not Looping In Exported RTF Document

Tags: php, export, rtf

I am exporting content from an MySQL database to a Word Template (RTF) via PHP.

There is a section, "Appendix B", which should display all the Acronyms found for a record.   The minimum records to appear for this section is 90 (i.e. these are standard acronyms (tblAcronyms) that each record will have); however the maximum records are unknown since users can add to this listing (tblAppendixB).

The Word (i.e. RTF) document should display all the records found, however, it is only displaying the first record.

This is what I have thus far:

```
<?php
....

#Retrieve Appendix B records
$qry_get_AppB = "SELECT vAcronym, vAcronymDesc FROM tblAcronyms
                   UNION SELECT vAcronym, vAcronymDesc FROM tblAppendixB
                     WHERE fkID = ". $i_fk_id . " ORDER BY vAcronym ASC";
$qry_appb_result = mysql_query($qry_get_AppB);
$qryAppBno_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry_appb_result);    

//Generate the headers to help a browser choose the correct location
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$vProgramName.'_rec.rtf");

//Open the template file
$tfilename = 'Appb_Template.rtf';
$fp = fopen($tfilename, 'r');

//Read the template into a variable
$toutput = fread($fp, filesize($tfilename));

fclose($fp);

//Replace the place holders in the template with data
if($qryAppBno_rows > 0)
{
  while($rowAppB = mysql_fetch_array($qry_appb_result)) 
  {
     $vAppB = $rowAppB['vAcronym'] . '-' . $rowAppB['vAcronymDesc'] . "\r\n";
     $toutput = str_replace('<<vAppB>>', $vAppB, $toutput);
  }
}

//Send the generated document to the browser
echo $toutput;

?>
```

I have searched this forum and others but have yet to find a solution.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not quite sure what your template looks like, but I guess, you only have 1 place holder named `<<vAppB>>`. In your 1st iteration (if there is any data available) you replace that placeholder with your 1st data entry. In this fact only one placeholder is shown.

May rewrite your code to something similar to this

```
... //do your stuff
$newLine = "\r\n";
$appendix = "";
while($rowAppB = mysql_fetch_array($qry_appb_result)) {
    $appendix .= $rowAppB['vAcronym'] . '-' . $rowAppB['vAcronymDesc'] . $newLine;
}
$toutput = str_replace('<<vAppB>>', $appendix, $toutput);
...//do some other stuff
```

Just simple prototyping, so you may have to do some additional work.

The trick is to `collect` all entries you got and than replace it with your placeholder :)

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea on how to resolve my problem.  When I echo the variable I receive all the records (i.e. collecting all the entries; a good thing); so I tried creating another variable that will then store those values (i.e. $appendix_result = $appendix) and then did $toutput = str_replace('<vAppB>>', $appendix_result, $toutput); but that didn't work either.  Was I almost on the right track as to what you suggested???

Comment: I've made some modifications ... it is now collecting all the entries and exporting them to the Word template, however, it is not breaking (i.e. inserting a new line break); the content runs together.  This is what I have .... while($rowAppB = mysql_fetch_array($qry_appb_result)) {
    $vAppendixB[] = $rowAppB['vAcronym'] . '-' . $rowAppB['vAcronymDesc'] . $t_newline;
$vAppB = implode($t_newline, $vAppendixB); }
$toutput = str_replace('<<vAppB>>', $vAppB, $toutput);   I know that I'm close, but can't figure out what I am missing.  Again, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem; I had to use "\par" instead of "\r\n" for MS Word (RTF) to recognize it as a paragraph mark.  Here is the modified code that now works:

```
<?php
....

$t_newline = "\par";

#Retrieve Appendix B records
$qry_get_AppB = "SELECT vAcronym, vAcronymDesc FROM tblAcronyms
               UNION SELECT vAcronym, vAcronymDesc FROM tblAppendixB
                 WHERE fkID = ". $i_fk_id . " ORDER BY vAcronym ASC";
$qry_appb_result = mysql_query($qry_get_AppB);
$qryAppBno_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry_appb_result);    

//Generate the headers to help a browser choose the correct location
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$vProgramName.'_rec.rtf");

//Open the template file
$tfilename = 'Appb_Template.rtf';
$fp = fopen($tfilename, 'r');

//Read the template into a variable
$toutput = fread($fp, filesize($tfilename));

fclose($fp);

//Replace the place holders in the template with data
if($qryAppBno_rows > 0)
{
   while($rowAppB = mysql_fetch_array($qry_appb_result)) 
   {
       $vAppendixB[] = $rowAppB['vAcronym'] . '-' . $rowAppB['vAcronymDesc'] . $t_newline;
       $vAppB = implode(" ", $vAppendixB);
   }
}

$toutput = str_replace('<<vAppB>>', $vAppB, $toutput);

//Send the generated document to the browser
echo $toutput;

?>
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.   :-)